# Unity timer stops the first time it is called

Tags: c#, timer, unity-game-engine

I've created a timer event that is suppose to trigger whenever my timer reaches a set goal. However, when I first trigger my timer it gets to a certain length, then just stops. However, if I trigger the timer again, it works as intended and I have no idea where this is happening.

Could someone please take a look at my timer code to see where this issue may lay? I've searched for a day but can't pin point it.

Below is ever instance where I do something with my timer in my main class. Some stuff has been omitted for clarity sake.

```
public float start_time;
public float look_at_time;
public float end_time;
private bool track_timer = false;

//this is called from a different class but acts as my start method
public void Setup()
{
    start_time      = 0;
    running_time    = 0;    

    ResetTimer();
}

void Update () 
{
    bool updateTimer = (track_timer && lastHitObject != null);
    Check(updateTimer);
            MyMethod();
}

void ResetTimer()
{
    start_time      = 0.0f;
    running_time    = 0f;
    track_timer     = false;
}
void MyMethod()
{
  if(argument 1)
  {
    if(argument 2)
    { 
       track_timer = false;
     }
  }

else 
   track_timer = false;
}

void Check(bool updateTimer)
{
    if(updateTimer)
    {
        start_time      += Time.deltaTime;
        running_time    += Time.deltaTime;
        if ( running_time >= end_time )
        {
            track_timer = false;
        }
    }   
    else
        end_time = Time.time;
}
```

Comment: Could I make a suggestion?  You've posted this same script over several questions, each with a different issue, and piecemeal'd it together from our responses.  Perhaps it's time to step back and redesign/refactor your code a bit and then asking a more focused question.

Answer (score 0):

I really dont understand what you're doing in your code, try to simplify it! You can either use [Invoke](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html), with a second argument of the time, or do something like this:

```
class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float SecondsToWait;

    private float timeCounter;

    void OnEnable() {
        timeCounter = 0;
    }

    void Update() {
        timeCounter += Time.deltaTime;

        if(timeCounter >= SecondsToWait)
        {
            enabled = false; //Disable this object
            doMyMethod();
        }
    }

    private void doMyMethod() {
        Debug.Log("Doing stuff!");
    }
}
```

If you want to stop it, just disable. If you want to run it, just enable it again.